# How to catch uncaught type errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following start to my jQuery:

```
(function($) {
    $.widget('ui.hbTags', {
        options: {
            availableTags: [],
            node: false,
            tagList: false,
            existingTags: false,
            placeholder: false,
            ajaxUrl: false,
            existingUrl: false,
            csrftoken: false
        },
```

However, I get `uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function` at line 2. I know this is because `ui.hbTags` is not an element on every page, but how to I prevent this problem?

Comment: `if ($('ui.hbTags'))`

Comment: why not add it on specific page only where needed

Comment: @EhsanSajjad because that's not efficient for best practice page load times. You should concatenate and then distribute to a CDN.

Answer (score 0):

I would just check that the tag is on the page before I call the widget.

```
(function($) {
    if($('ui.hbTags').length > 0) {
        $.widget('ui.hbTags', {
            options: {
                availableTags: [],
                node: false,
                tagList: false,
                existingTags: false,
                placeholder: false,
                ajaxUrl: false,
                existingUrl: false,
                csrftoken: false
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

If (typeof $(el) not equal 'undefined')
Use this psedo code before your code